# Canadian Currency in Authorize.Net

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have a .NET C# application that uses the Auth.NET SDK to process payments.  My client now would like to now add Canadian currency and support Canada but I don't see any documentation around how to do it.  Is there a way to specify that it is Canadian currency?  The product prices are held in the database the same way we format US dollars - they are obviously just different amounts.  Any feedback would be great as this is high importance for my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorize.Net supports a single currency per gateway account, so if you need to accept payments in multiple currencies, your client must have multiple gateway accounts and your code must switch to the correct currency.